# Locale dependent Week of Year in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to get Week of Year. For this I am using `tm * __CRTDECL localtime(const time_t * _Time)` but I am not getting desired result which should be locale dependent. So I was looking for solution and some more information. I have found that there is API in JAVA `Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);`.So I am just wondering whether there is such API in c/c++ as I did not find any ( not sure ). If not can anybody give me some time pointers *to get Week of Year locale dependant.*

The code I am using

```
int MyClass::getCalendarWeek(time_t time, int * p_year) 
{    
    // Get tm structure of time parameter
    tm* pCurrentTm = localtime(&time);

    // determine Thursday in that week
    LONG offSet = 4 - pCurrentTm->tm_wday;
    if (offSet >= 4) {
        offSet = -3;        // Sunday
    }
    time += offSet * 86400L;
    pCurrentTm = localtime(&time);
    if (p_year) {
        *p_year = pCurrentTm->tm_year + 1900;// year of current calendar week
    }
    return (pCurrentTm->tm_yday + 7) / 7;   // current calendar week
}
```

Output:

11 July is in week 28 when running most locales that have monday as first day of the week, but it is week 29 for sunday as first day of week.

Comment: Please show the actual and the desired results.

Comment: okay, I will add it

Comment: Boost.DateTime provides such functionnalities : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but maybe it helps you out. In germany the 4. January is always in week 1. From this point you can calculate the other weeks.

Comment: OK got it. No, there's no generic/localised calendar support in the C++ standard. Boost may help.

Comment: N.B. simply adding/subtracting 86400 seconds may cause you to step two days instead of one during a DST change.